# Moblog - Entries aren't created, no error

Tags: templates, fields

I've managed to get the moblog to work previously, but now, I can't even get it to create an entry. If there are no emails in the mailbox I'm checking, it says `"No valid emails were found"`, so it seems it manages to connect just fine. But if I actually send an email to that address with the correct Moblog Subject Prefix, I get no error message. But there are no entries created either. Even the simplest moblog template with only `{text}` doesn't work. No entries are created. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally managed to fix this issue. First of all, I suspected that the default field in the moblog config could be the culprit. So it became apparent that moblog only supports textarea and textfield by default. So the default field was empty in my moblog configuration.

Editing the ExpressionEngine $default_config to include the following `'moblog_allow_nontextareas' => 'y',` made it possible to select all my channel fields as default field. And thus, the post was created as expected. This really is badly documented by EllisLag. But then again, it's not a very used feature anyway.